# In spark, if one column contains a lot of data does this affect the performance of queries on other columns?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, parquet

Let's assume that I'm using spark and storing data in parquet format. I have a table with multiple columns, one of which may contain a relatively large amount of data (for example let's say it could contain a 10000 word string).

Now I want to make a simple query on the number of rows for a given partition of data. I would expect that it wouldn't matter how much data is in one of the columns. As I understand it, parquet is a columnar format so it stores and operates on data column-wise. So it could just load one of the columns with a small amount of data and count the rows. But I'm finding that when a column contains large data it slows down the query performance. In spark UI I can see that the input data is much larger. This is true even if the query explicitly excludes that column.

Is this the expected behavior? Isn't the advantage of columnar data specifically to improve performance in cases like this?

Comment: Not sure your evidence adds up. Did you do an .explain() ?